# Estimator in statistics: Correlating random variable with real life example

Tags: statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation

An estimator is a process to construct estimates for a quantity `q` based on a random sample $X_1$,$X_{2}$, ..., $X_{n}$.

So suppose we want to check how many hours of tv are being watched by people in the US. I can't take into consideration the whole population of millions of people. Instead I consider $1000$ of them. So
$X_1,X_2, ..., X_{1000}$ is denoting the number of hours for each of the $1000$ people. And why are these variables? Because $X_1$ can take any value from $0-24$, we don't know for sure. Is this realization correct?

Also please feel free to share any point that a person can miss when reading this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Variables can take on different values for repeats of the same situation.  A single random sample is the values of a set of "draws" from a population.

In probability we reason from a distribution to data; in statistics we reason from data to a distribution or model.  We want to know about the full population, but without a census, that is not possible.  So we take our "best guess" which is found using statistics.